# How can i get these HTML/XML-Tags as a String via PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml

i need some table values as String in my php script.

The HTML-File looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">

...

<body>

....

<div class="page">
<div class="content">
<div class="left">
<table class="info_table">
<tbody>
<tr id="info_id_352">
        <td class="info_iddata"><a href="Ice-Tea">Icetea</a></td>
        <td style="width: 32px;"><div class="enough_available"></div></td>
        <td class="drink-status drink-enoughavailable">Available</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

...

</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here i need the following XML-tags and values:

From :

- value of the a-href-link (in this example the value "Icetea")
- The xml-tag of of the second field (in this example "enough_available")
- The xml-tag and the value of the third field (here: "drink-status drink-enoughavailable" and "Available"

I tried this (first value "IceTea) with the following lines:

```
$pagestring = file_get_contents("./index.html");
$drinkxml = new DOMDocument();
$drinkxml->loadHTML($pagestring);
$drinkxml->getElementsByTagNameNs('info_id_352', '*') as $tr ;
echo current($tr->getElementsByTagName('a'))->nodeValue;
```

With these lines i get the following php error on the shell:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_AS in /home/phpscripts/bin/drinkstatus/php/drinkstatus.php on line 44
```

Has anyone some hints to get the xml-values and the class-names?

Comment: `$drinkxml->getElementsByTagNameNs('info_id_352', '*') as $tr ;` --- what does it mean? Where have you seen such an `as` operator usage?

Comment: hi - I tried to find some answers and found this page: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-domnodelist-could-not-be-940500.html I found out, that the result isn't a string, instead it is a DOMNodeList, so I tried to use the code example on this page to get this as a String - after many edits and tries I got these code lines...the answer is I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error, line 44, points to this line: 
`$drinkxml->getElementsByTagNameNs('info_id_352', '*') as $tr ;`.

You can't use an "as" in that manner. You would want to do this if you were creating a FOR EACH loop. But outside of that, nadda.

**Try creating a variable instead...by replacing the line above with the one below:**

```
$tr = $drinkxml->getElementsByTagNameNs('info_id_352', '*');
```

Comment: I'm assuming the error, line 44, points to this line: --- yes you are right. after using your line (now line 45) i got this error (the echo line is line 46): PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementByTagName() in /home/phpscripts/bin/drinktatus/php/drinkstatus2.php on line 46

Comment: You REPLACED the line with my new one, right? Replace, don't add.

Comment: of course - i commented the old line out (#) and used your line instead. Now i have the first three php lines from my initial question, your line and the echo-line to view the content of the <a href-html-tag

Comment: Try using this for the echo line, I can't test but I think that `->nodeValue` should be inside the brackets... `echo current($tr->getElementsByTagName('a')->nodeValue);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$drinkxml->getElementsByTagNameNs('info_id_352', '*') as $tr ;
```

Is a syntax error since 'as' is not a keyword outside of  a foreach condition. Try assigning tr:

```
$tr = $drinkxml->getElementsByTagNameNs('info_id_352', '*');
```

GetElementsByTagNameNs returns a node list object, so that should work for the next method call.

http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagnamens.php

Comment: Is there an echo in here? :p If you read my answer you would have saw I said exactly the same thing - which brought up another issue...

Comment: Sorry Mike, I'm just on my phone here and didn't see your answer.